# Sencha buil MVC3 file

Tags: extjs

I am unable to run sencha build command for my MVC application in ExtJs. but sencha create jsb command has successfully generated the file

```
{
"projectName": "Project Name",
"licenseText": "Copyright(c) 2011 Company Name",
"builds": [
    {
        "name": "All Classes",
        "target": "all-classes.js",
        "options": {
            "debug": true
        },
        "files": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Application - Production",
        "target": "app-all.js",
        "compress": true,
        "files": [
            {
                "path": "",
                "name": "all-classes.js"
            },
            {
                "path": "",
                "name": "app.js"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"resources": []
}
```

Can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Seems the jsb file it is not sucessfully created, the files of your application should be in "files" in the builds section but it isn't.
Like this:

```
...
"builds": [
    {
        "name": "All Classes",
        "target": "all-classes.js",
        "options": {
            "debug": true
        },
        "files": [{
                "path": "app/controller",
                "name": "MyController.js"
            }, {
              ... etc
            }]
    },
...
```

What version of the sdk are you using?